# how to cc a custom email in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, email, custom, email-templates

I have a custom module and I have created the email template for the module too.

I want to cc the email from the module to some specific emails.

Below is my code which I have tried, but CC email is not working.

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('customer_product_return_template');
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['return_ref']  = $return_ref;
$emailTemplate->addBcc("abc@gmail.com");
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
/* Sender Name */
$sender = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'); 
/* Sender Email */
$sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Manufactures');
$mail->setToEmail(array($manufacture_email,'xxxxxx@gmail.com'));
$mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
$mail->setSubject('Product Return Request from the customer');
$mail->setFromEmail($sender_email);
$mail->setFromName("abc trades ");

$mail->setType('html');
try {
    $mail->send();
}catch (Exception $e) {

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
    //$this->_redirect('');
}
```

I tried to add these lines too, but nothing works for me

```
//$mail->addBcc('xxxx@gmail.com');
//$mail->setCc(array('a1h1is@gmail.com.com','xxssxx@gmail.com'));
```

I hope definitely someone has faced the same issue and fixed it, Please help me on this.

**UPDATE**

Here my issue is , i guess that i am using both

`$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');`

**and**

`$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');`

It would be great pleasure if some one explain this point. Thanks

Comment: You should get an Fatal Error here for missing catch block. `$emailTemplate->addBcc` should normaly work for transactional emails.

Comment: @sv3n what do you mean by catch block,are referring on try catch

Comment: When using `try {}` there should also be `catch (Exception $e) {}`

Comment: i have catch block too, but there was nothing exception print here

Answer (score 3):

```
try{
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
  $mail->getMail()->addCc('abc@gmail.com');  
}
catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.This i snot working for me, What i am missing i cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$mail->getMail()->addCc('zzz@gmail.com');`

Answer (score 0):

**CC Email :**

```
$mail->getMail()->addCc('abc@gmail.com');
```

**BCC Email :**

```
$mail->getMail()->addBcc('abc@gmail.com');
```

**Note: Additional parameter**

`addTo()` and `addCc()` accept a second optional parameter that is used as a human-readable name of the recipient for the header. Double quotation is changed to single quotation and angle brackets to square brackets in the parameter.

**Note: Optional Usage**

All three of these methods can also accept an array of email addresses to add instead of one at a time. In the case of `addTo()` and `addCc()`, they can be associative arrays where the key is the human readable name for the recipient.

Please check for more reference

https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.mail.adding-recipients.html